# Python: Create DataFrame from highest frequency of occurrence per item

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, count, frequency

I have a dataframe as given below

```
data = {
    'Code': ['P', 'J', 'M', 'Y', 'P', 'Z', 'P', 'P', 'J', 'P', 'J', 'M', 'P', 'Z', 'Y', 'M', 'Z', 'J', 'J'],
    'Value': [10, 10, 20, 30, 10, 40, 50, 10, 10, 20, 10, 50, 60, 40, 30, 20, 40, 20, 10]
}

example = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Using Python 3, I want to create another dataframe from the dataframe `example` such that the **Code** associated with the greater number of **Value** is obtained.

The new dataframe should look like **solution** below

```
output = {'Code': ['J', 'M', 'Y', 'Z', 'P', 'M'],'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50]}

solution = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

As can be seen, J has more association to Value 10 than other Code so J is selected, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that returns the most occurring items and apply it to the grouped elements. Finally explode to list to rows.

```
>>> def most_occurring(grp):
...     res = Counter(grp)
...     highest = max(res.values())
...     return  [k for k, v in res.items() if v == highest]
... 
>>> example.groupby('Value')['Code'].apply(lambda x: most_occurring(x)).explode().reset_index()
   Value Code
0     10    J
1     20    M
2     30    Y
3     40    Z
4     50    P
5     50    M
6     60    P
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need something like this:

```
grouped = example.groupby(['Code', 'Value']).indices
arr_tmp = []
[arr_tmp.append([i[0], i[1], len(grouped[i])]) for i in grouped]#['Int64Index'])
output = pd.DataFrame(data=arr_tmp, columns=['Code', 'Value', 'index_count'])
output = output.sort_values(by=['index_count'], ascending=False)
output.reset_index(inplace=True)
output
```